# New Project from Existing Files пропал

Tags: php, phpstorm

В PhpStorm пропал пункт File -> New Project from Existing Files, подскажите куда копать, не могу создать проект...

Comment: а просто open direcotоry не подходит?

Comment: В техподдержку :D А вообще, я всегда просто открываю проект, как сказал @teran.

Answer (score 1):

Можно нажать `File` → `New Project`, далее выбрать директорию с проектом и нажать `Create`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откроется окно с предупреждением, что директория не пуста, хотите ли вы создать проект из имеющихся файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажать "Да" (Yes)